# sympy's atan2 not full numerical evaluation

Tags: sympy, atan2

I am using sympy's atan2 and for certain values it isn't giving me the full numerical evaluation but giving me a (value + pi)

```
from sympy import atan2
print(atan2(0.0037, -0.056))
```

gives the following output:

> -0.0659755361339305 + pi

I want the code to give the numberical value without the "+ pi", in this case 3.07402446387

mpmath's mpf function solves this issue but gives me error messages in other parts of my code. Is there another way of doing this?

Comment: Try using the numerical conversion functions/methods of sympy; see [here](http://docs.sympy.org/dev/modules/evalf.html). Of course, you can always use  the  equivalent `numpy` function, which is probably faster.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
from sympy import atan2
print(atan2(0.0037, -0.056).evalf())
```

Does excatly what you want.

```
from sympy import atan2
print(atan2(0.0037, -0.056).evalf(30))
```

Gives you the numerical result with 30 digits precision.